# HTML nested table output not as expected

Tags: html, web

I created a nested table as per the section 3 challenge. But I don't get tables in the right alignment. Please see the picture I included below. The code I used is posted below too. Please feel free to check.  Here you can see the second table is not starting exactly at the top.
[image]

The body part of HTML code is listed below. Please refer and point me where I made my mistake.

```
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> <img src="images/img11.png" alt="Master Oggway Quotes"></td>
      <td>
        <h1>No Name</h1>
        <p>
          <em>Embedded Engineer and </em>
          <strong>a life long learner</strong>
        </p>
        <p>This is my website I will put some awesome electronics and computer science experiment I do here.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table cellspacing="20">
  <hr>
  <h3>Techinical Background</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Bachelor Degree in ECE</li>
    <li>3 year experience in Embedded Engineering</li>
    <li>C programmer, Python, web development, C++ </li>
    <li>Linux shell scripting plus embedded linux programming</li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
  <h3>WORK EXPERIENCE</h3>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Experience</th>
      </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>2018-2019</td>
        <td>SMEC LABS as Juniour Embedded Engineer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2019-PRESENT</td>
        <td>QIS as Seniour Embedded Engineer</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <hr>
  <h3>My Hobbies</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>Electronics DIY experimenting and Programming</li>
    <li>Web development <a href="Some Link">Youtuber</a> and Blogging</li>
    <li>GAME programming in Scratch and C++</li>
    <li>Reading techinical articles and books</li>
    <li>Dance, Swim and video games</li>
  </ol>
  <hr>
  <h3>SKILLS</h3>
  <table cellspacing="20">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellspacing="20">
          <tr>
            <td>Embedded C, C++</td>
            <td> &#10026;&#10026;&#10026;&#10026;&#10026;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>PCB Design using KiCAD</td>
            <td> &#10026;&#10026;&#10026;&#10026;&#10026;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Web Designing and Python Programming</td>
            <td> &#10026;&#10026;&#10026;&#10026;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Embedded Linux and Linux System Programming</td>
            <td> &#10026;&#10026;&#10026;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table cellspacing="20">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">Hardware debugging using DSO logic analyzer etc</td>
            <td valign="top"> &#10026;&#10026;&#10026;&#10026;&#10026;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">IoT and Networking</td>
            <td valign="top"> &#10026;&#10026;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>

  <h3><a href="hobbies.html" target="_blank">Hobbies Explained</a></h3>
  <h3><a href="contact.html" target="_blank">CONTACT ME</a></h3>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to vertically align the contents of the `td`

```html
<td valign="top">
   <table> ...</table>
</td>
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/socorucebe/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't working in my case. I will put my entire code, it just only a few lines.

Comment: `valign` has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) for about 15 years or more.